# How to calculate CSS vh unit to match previous configuration defned with px?

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

Recently, Wikimedia upgraded an HTML page layout used for editing, by changing the CSS units from **px** to **vh**.

The problem is that this HTML page also contains several fixed height text boxes [listed below], and now these are elongated and makes text editing impossible.

The values in the linked image, were based on my screen resolution of 1664 x 936 [16:9].

It's unknown to me which of the sizes in the linked image **vh** is based on.

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/File:Resolution_and_inner_and_outer_windows_sizes.jpg

Is there a way to fix these textboxes position in this dynamic height setting?

[edit space with blank blue areas which need to be eliminated](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/File:220926_edit_space_with_blank_blue_areas_.jpg)

```
/* previously 300px - height of the text image window in the page edit view */

    .prp-page-image-openseadragon-horizontal {
        width:100% !important;
        max-height:calc(100vh - 636px);
        min-height:calc(100vh - 636px);
    }
    
    /* previously 60px - header and footer windows height  in edit view */
    #wpHeaderTextbox, #wpFooterTextbox {
        font-size:120% !important;
        max-height:calc(100vh - 876px;
        min-height:calc(100vh - 876px);
        color: #000 !important;
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }
    
    /* previously = 300px - main text area  in edit view */
    .mw-editform #wpTextbox1 {
        display:block !important;
        font-size:120% !important;
        max-height:calc(100vh - 636px);
        min-height:calc(100vh - 636px);
        color: #000 !important;
        background-color: #F5F5F5 !important;
    }
```

Comment: there is a reason to use relative instead of absolute units for reasons of `responsive web design`. So instead of converting your fixed pixels that works on your screen you should learn to use relative units such as `em`, `rem`, and `vh/vw` that the design will work on all screens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and although you are correct in general, this does not apply because it's my personal workspace with it's own CSS. Changes affect no one else but me. 

The application of "hv" increases this textbox height and I lose access to editing toolbar, which is mounted on this textbox frame beyond visibility, as well as adds hundreds of pixels to the textbox height.